# How to get all substrings in a list of characters (python)

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, iteration

I want to iterate over a list of characters

```
temp = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '#', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

so that I can obtain two strings, `"hello"` and `"world"`

My current way to do this is:

```
#temp is the name of the list
#temp2 is the starting index of the first alphabetical character found
for j in range(len(temp)):
    if temp[j].isalpha() and temp[j-1] != '#':
            temp2 = j
            while (temp[temp2].isalpha() and temp2 < len(temp)-1:
                temp2 += 1
            print(temp[j:temp2+1])
            j = temp2
```

The issue is that this prints out

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
['e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
['l', 'l', 'o']
['l', 'o']
['o']
```

etc. How can I print out only the full valid string?

Edit: I should have been more specific about what constitutes a "valid" string. A string is valid as long as all characters within it are either alphabetical or numerical. I didn't include the "isnumerical()" method within my check conditions because it isn't particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'valid string'? Because "hello#world" is still a valid string although It can be discussed if it's an actual english word or phrase

Comment: what  do you consider valid and what can be the delimiters?

Comment: A string is valid if it contains only either numerical or alphabetical characters. Any other character marks the end of that string, and the next string will begin where the next character is either an alphabetical or numerical character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want only `hello` and `world` and your words are always `#` seperated, you can easily do it by using [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#join) and [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> temp = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '#', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> "".join(temp).split('#')
['hello', 'world']
```

Further more if you need to `print` the full valid string you need to

```
>>> t = "".join(temp).split('#')
>>> print(' '.join(t))
hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
''.join(temp).split('#')
```

Answer (score 1):

`List` has the method `index` which returns position of an element. You can use slicing to join the characters.

```
In [10]: temp = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '#', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
In [11]: pos = temp.index('#')
In [14]: ''.join(temp[:pos])
Out[14]: 'hello'
In [17]: ''.join(temp[pos+1:])
Out[17]: 'world'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want alphas just use [isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) replacing the  `#`  and any other non letters with a space and then split of you want a list of words:

```
print("".join(x  if x.isalpha() else " " for x in temp).split())
```

If you want both words in a single string replace the `#` with a space and join using the conditional  expression :

```
print("".join(x if x.isalpha() else " " for x in temp))
hello world
```

To do it using a loop like you own code just iterate over items and add to the output string is isalpha else add a space to the output:

```
out = ""
for s in temp:
    if s.isalpha():
        out += s
    else:
        out += " "
```

Using a loop to get a list of words:

```
words  = []
out = ""
for s in temp:
    if s.isalpha():
        out += s
    else:
        words.append(out)
        out = ""
```

Comment: Note for OP - Documentation for [str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate, itertools-based solution:

```
>>> temp = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '#', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> import itertools
>>> ["".join(str)
     for isstr, str in itertools.groupby(temp, lambda c: c != '#') 
     if isstr]
['hello', 'world']
```

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is used to ... well ... *group* consecutive items depending if they are of not equal to `#`. The comprehension list will discard the sub-lists containing only `#` and `join` the non-`#` sub-lists.

The only advantage is that way, you don't have to build the full-string just to split it afterward. Probably only relevant if the string in really long.